# Velocity randomizer - Any free MIDI editor with this feature?

Tags: midi, daw, editor

I am wondering if there is any free software that allows you to randomize the velocity in a MIDI file by x amount of %?

I don't want to spend a fortune on FL Studio as the velocity randomizer is literally the only feature I am ever going to use, I'm a poor student and I don't make music for a living.

Here is a link to a YouTube video explaining the feature I am looking for:

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most user-friendly option, since some learning is required, but there are free programming software ([Pure Data](https://puredata.info/), [SuperCollider](https://supercollider.github.io/), etc.) that will allow you to create your own MIDI editor to read MIDI files, manipulate the data (i.e. randomizing note velocity values in a given range) and output the results.

Such tools may take time to master, depending on how advanced you want to get- but for someone who has basic knowledge, a velocity randomizer is pretty straightforward to put together themselves. Once you get a hang of it, you will have far less need to buy plugins. It seems like you are looking for something specific that no free plugin is doing for you, so hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Forget it.

Variations (timing, volume, sound, pitch) in well performed music are not random, they are the phrasing that the musician inserts and they reflect his ability to live the music as he plays. Randomness is useless.

Many of us have never developed the ability to play long nor busy passages enjoyably. Fortunately electronic instruments and quantizing stripe off a good amount of the random sloppiness if  we record our playing into a sequencer. A random wrong hit is easy to fix and doing step time input to a grid removes all randomness. Of course, that "robotic perfectness" can also be seen as a style. Kraftwerk built its whole art on it when the concept was new in recorded music (see NOTE1)

**My advice:** make systematic variations that you decide. If you have got what's needed to hear which makes live playing enjoyable to listen you quite soon learn what systematic variations can insert to a fully robotic sequence. You can insert volume and modulation envelopes and use slight systematic timing displacements. Some sequencers even have groove quantization templates for fast experimenting.

Know that timing displacements and volume variations work together, they are not independent for the listener.

NOTE1 The concept is an old one. There has been clockenspiels and hurdy-gurdies hundreds of years.

The pneumatic paper roll player pianos do not belong to the same class because the mechanism was gradually developed to be able to repeat exactly the performances of competent players. More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Player_piano

Comment: Well, I am mostly making MIDI's for my youtube channel, making piano tutorials with synthesia so i dont really focus on making it super perfect. i only have velocity at right hand around 80 while the velocity for left hand is usually 5 or 10 lower. The other function is the sustain pedal, but that is really all. My MIDI's are super basic really.

The closest i have come to the variations as you describe must probably be this video as i experimented with different velocity values at the different part of the songs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAzoRVSqDF8

Comment: Everything about the MIDI has been made using a combination of Anvil Studio and MidiEditor

https://www.anvilstudio.com/
http://www.midieditor.org/


Here is the link to the MIDI file to this video if you want to take a look (link wil expire at the end of the month): https://studntnu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hdsun_ntnu_no/EXp86t3Hq6xFjjWjWQ0YTekBGh_io989I1bKOyTvFE-8aA?e=1mRY35

Comment: The earliest stage of my videos and MIDIs was that every note had the velocity maxed out at 127. this was clearly a mistake. i only thought it meant how loud the note would be (which is partly correct), not how hard the keys were pressed. now i also use sforzando and ivy piano soundfont as microsoft wavetable synth sounds horrible in comparison. But using sforzando created an another issue where a note suddenly become mute if the same note is pressed right after another, but from two different tracks so i have to make third track with the two first tracks merged so "solve" that issue

Answer (score -1):

Reaper will do it and has a free trial.  Any decent MIDI sequencer should have this feature.

Edit: As the only person in this thread who has given a direct, concise and correct answer to this user's question, I take strong exception to the downvote.

Comment: hm.. all i found so far is that i need to install plugins or something. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=er38jXJRDVo&ab_channel=IDDQDSound
does not look user friendly, but i will look deeper into it